# Android intentoptions for SMS standard app and EMail standard app

Tags: android, email, sms, android-intent

Is it possible to add a option to the sms and email app of android?

I want to add a option who call my activity and send me the sms text or email text.
Is it possible?

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. Do you want to pass information *to* the SMS/email app to compose a new message? Do you want to be informed of new incoming SMS or email?

Comment: No i want to add an option to the menu of the standard sms and email programs...

On Click it should open my app with the given extras (email id or sms id)....

I've found intentoptions in the docu, and this is what i need, but did the sms and email program implement this?

Answer (score 0):

You are asking if it is possible to sms from your app.
Yes, its possible. Try using `SMS Manager API`. You can find out about SMS Manage API  on Android Developers here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html

or check out this tutorial example:
http://www.mavenscientists.com/2013/09/how-to-send-sms-in-android_20.html

You also want your app to show up when you want to send sms or an email.
Yes, this is possible.

Try using Implicit Intents in your application.

Comment: Thanks I do not want to send a SMS, I wanted to add a share menu to the SMS app.

But this is not possible.

Comment: Link broken **->** http://www.mavenscientists.com/2013/09/how-to-send-sms-in-android_20.html